# Yarn with Elixir CircleCI configuration: couldn't find a package.json file

Tags: docker, elixir, package.json, yarnpkg, circleci

I have following configuration on CircleCI (my_cms/.circleci/config.iml):

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build_node:
    working_directory: ~/my_cms/apps/my_cms_web/assets
    docker:
      - image: node:8.9
    environment:
      - MIX_ENV: "test"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: yarn install
      - run: yarn test

  build_elixir:
    working_directory: ~/my_cms
    docker:
      - image: elixir:1.5.2
      - image: postgres:9.6.3
    environment:
      - MIX_ENV: "test"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: mix deps.get
      - run:
          command: mix deps.compile
          working_directory: ~/my_cms/apps/my_cms_core
      - run:
          command: mix deps.compile
          working_directory: ~/my_cms/apps/my_cms_web

workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - build_node
      - build_elixir
```

This is not full listing but I think it should be enough to catch the problem. CircleCI goes through `build_elixir` job successfully. But the following error stops `build_node` job:

> !/bin/bash -eo pipefail
>  
>   yarn test
>  yarn run v1.3.2
>  error Couldn't find a package.json file in
>   "/root/gem_cms/apps/gem_cms_web/assets"
>  info Visit
>   Exited with code 1

I have following files in the repo:

- my_cms/mix.exs
- my_cms/apps/my_cms_core/mix.exs
- my_cms/apps/my_cms_web/mix.exs
- my_cms/apps/my_cms_web/assets/package.json

`yarn` works locally in `my_cms/apps/my_cms_web/assets` folder without any issues, but I can't make him work remotely via CircleCI. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking that the file is actually in git with `git ls-files | grep package.json`. Once you confirm it is in git then try adding some debugging commands to the circle config.

Some things you might want to try: `ls -l`, `pwd`.

I also notice that the directory in the error message does not match your config, which seems strange. Is that error message from an earlier build? The command doesn't match either.

Comment: Thanks for your participation! I was able to fix the issue by specifying "path" sub-property per each step command run section. So it was CircleCI configuration problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries the following configuration of node-build job gave me successfull build:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build_node:
    working_directory: ~/my_cms
    docker:
      - image: node:8.9
    environment:
      - MIX_ENV: "test"
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install Node Packages
          command: yarn install
          path: apps/my_cms_web/assets
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: yarn test
          path: apps/my_cms_web/assets
  ...
```